# Adding Property to Double Class

Tags: groovy

I am running a clustering algorithm that clusters a collection of collections of Doubles. However once the clustering is done, I would like to figure out to which parent class each Double belongs to.

```
class PatientMRNA {
     Patient patient
     MRNA mrna
     Double value
}
```

I am querying the database with hql and putting the selected values from the PatientMRNA table into a Collection like so:

```
[[x11,x12...x1m],[x21,x22...x2m]...[xn1, xn2, xnm]]
```

This collection gets clustered by a very nice algorithm found here: https://coviello.wordpress.com/2013/03/30/learning-functional-programming-a-k-means-implementation-in-groovy/

Once the clustering is done, our result is as follows:

```
[[centroid]: [[x?1, x?2...x?m],[x?1,x?2...x?m]...[x?1,x?2...x?m]] [centroid2]: [[],[]...[]]
```

Where each x array (belonging to a patient) value is randomized depending on the cluster it is assigned to.

My question is: Is there any way to extend the Double class in groovy so that it also has a PatientId property? Or should I really be looking at this problem in some other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

kocko is wrong, as long as ALL of your code is in Groovy, you can use the instance metaClass as shown here:

```
// a list of patients
def patients = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e' ]

// A list of doubles
def doubles  = [ 5.0, 6.0, 2.0, 1.0, 9.0 ]

// for each double, set it's patient property to the parent at the same index
def decorated = [doubles, patients].transpose().collect { dbl, patient ->
    dbl.metaClass.patient = patient
    dbl
}

// sort it for fun, to prove it works
def sortedDecorated = decorated.sort(false)

// and print each out
sortedDecorated.each {
    println "$it ${it.patient}"
}
```

That prints:

```
1.0 d
2.0 c
5.0 a
6.0 b
9.0 e
```

Of course, if you pass the list of doubles off to some Java code, then kocko is right as Java has no knowledge of the metaClass, so will just return you a list of plain undecorated Doubles

Comment: Pardon if this violates Stack Overflow rules, but I think I love you. Thank you so much!

Comment: Haha! Glad to help, have fun! x ;-)